# GeoServer WPS could not locate FeatureCollection in Catalog

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork, wps

I'm trying to execute wps request via the GeoNetwork3 mapView. The workflow is that the user selects an existing feature collection and then a point. After that, the request is being executed. The request format is xml and it's being submitted via post. Unfortunately the execute response is:

```
Could not locate {http://geonetwork-opensource.org/}Apotheken in catalog.
```

But the xml is build exactly like the one that's been sent via the wps request builder from the wps plugin on the GeoServer demo page.

My XML (only the relevant part):

```
<wps:Input>
<ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
<wps:Reference mimeType='text/xml' xlink:href='http://geoserver/wfs' method='POST'>
<wps:Body>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:gn='http://geonetwork-opensource.org/' service='wfs' version='1.0.0' outputFormat='GML2'>
<wfs:Query typeName='gn:Apotheken'/>
</wfs:GetFeature>
</wps:Body>
</wps:Reference>
</wps:Input>
```

WPS-Request Builder XML:

```
<wps:Input>
  <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
    <wps:Body>
      <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:gn="http://geonetwork-opensource.org/">
        <wfs:Query typeName="gn:apotheken"/>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
    </wps:Body>
  </wps:Reference>
</wps:Input>
```

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Turned out it had to be apotheken instead of Apotheken.

Answer (score 2):

The GeoServer WPS is case sensitive, that means, the FeatureCollection has to be named exactly like the FeatureCollection you've uploaded to GeoServer. GeoNetwork has transformed it to begin with an uppercase letter e.g. Apotheken instead of apotheken. So be aware of this.